# SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Tags: python

Eu estou usando o seguinte código:

```
Levels[track][level] > UnpaidMaxSkills[track] or self.inventory[track][level] += amount
```

Só que recebo o erro:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: O próprio erro está dizendo, você não pode usar uma atribuição como operador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não entendi exatamente o que você quer fazer com esse trecho de código, mas o erro ocorre por causa de um [*Augmented assignment statement*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) <del>(declaração de atribuição aumentada?)</del> em uma expressão.

Se li corretamente a documentação, quando há uma atribuição desse tipo, o interpretador Python avalia atribuir o que está na **direita** (expressão) e atribui para o que está na **esquerda** do operador (alvo). O resultado disso não pode ser usado em uma expressão.

No seu caso, ao usar o operador de atribuição `+=`, o Python está tentando atribuir `amount` a `Levels[track][level] > UnpaidMaxSkills[track] or self.inventory[track][level]`, mas isso não é algo que possa receber uma atribuição.

Não entendi perfeitamente o objetivo desse código, mas a solução é fazer o incremento fora da expressão ou outro tipo de verificação. Exemplo:

```py
if Levels[track][level] > UnpaidMaxSkills[track]:
    # fazer algo
else:
    self.inventory[track][level] += amount
    if self.inventory[track][level]:
        # fazer algo
```